# Getting wrong message using msgrcv and msgsnd commands in c

Tags: c, ipc, communication, msg

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct msg{
    long mtype;
}msg;

void child1();
void child2();
int queue_ids[2];
pid_t pid1;
pid_t pid2;

int main(){

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        key_t key = 2023+i;
        queue_ids[i] = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    }


    if( (pid1 = fork()) == 0)
        child1();
    if( (pid2 = fork()) == 0)
        child2();

    printf("SHould see 2 of those");
    sleep(50);

}

void child1(){

    msg msnd;
    msnd.mtype = 150;
    msgsnd(queue_ids[1], &msnd, sizeof(msg), 0);
    printf("child1 sent a message\n");
    sleep(450);
}

void child2(){
    sleep(10);
    msg *mrcv = (msg*) malloc(sizeof(msg));
    msgrcv(queue_ids[1],mrcv, sizeof(msg),0,0);
    printf("child2 recieved message. mtype = %ld\n", mrcv->mtype);
    kill(pid1, SIGKILL);
}
```

I tried to simply cummunicate between 2 processes. As I understand, using `msgrcv` with argument of msgtype = 0 should just read the first message in the queue. Since `child1` is the only one that sends messages to the queue, I expect to just read his message with mtype=150 as soon as it will be sent. But my output is the following:

```
child1 seng a message
child2 recieved message. mtype = 94063516914727
```

What can cause the problem?

Also, in child2, I tried to replace `msg *mrcv = (msg*) malloc(sizeof(msg));` with simplt `msg mrcv;` and then the call will be:

```
msgrcv(queue_ids[1], &mrcv, sizeof(msg),0,0);
```

But I got another error

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Why is that? when I declare `msg mrcv;` shouldnt the same amount of memory be allocated as when I am using `malloc` with `sizeof(msg)` ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("SHould see 2 of those");` or add a `'\n'` to the end of the string literal. Output to `stdout` is *line-buffered* and your output will not be seen until a `'\n'` is output or the program ends flushing the output streams. (you could use `puts()` instead which automatically appends a `'\n'` -- since there are no conversions present). Additionally, you must compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or have that defined somewhere so `kill()` is not implicitly defined. (`50` seconds is a long time to wait ... which suggest reading `man 2 wait` may help)

Comment: Your `struct msg` is missing `char mtext[1]`, see `man 2 msgsnd`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the mtext is not necessary

Comment: Yes, it will compile without warning without it, but when specified in the man page -- and chasing a stack smashing error, having the pointer so your implementation of `msgsnd` and `msgrcv` can reserve the number of bytes required there -- may make a difference. It doesn't with gcc, but there is no guarantee on other compilers.

Comment: You are not using `msgsnd` and `msgrcv` correctly. The third argument should **not** be the size of the `struct`.

Comment: @n.m. So what should it be?

Comment: The man page says exactly what it should be...

Comment: @n.m. And it says it should be the size of the struct...

Comment: It most certainly doesn't on my system. "The  mtext field is an array (or other structure) whose size is specified by msgsz, a nonnegative integer value.  Messages of zero length (i.e., no mtext field) are  permitted." What does yours say?

Comment: @n.m. - I think the issue here is he is simply sending a msgtype = `150` and no text so the OP is relying on messages of zero length being permitted and omitting the `mtext` member. I can't find direct support for omitting it, but the man page does permit a message length of zero. Whether you read that to be the empty-string mandating `mtext[1]` for the nul-character or no array at all isn't spelled out in the man page and will likely take looking at the source code to determine which it is. Including `mtext[1]` and initializing the struct zero to begin with seems the best approach.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The size parameter is for the size of the *text*. If there is no text, the parameter value should be zero (and the program actually works when modified this way). Setting the size to sizeof(msg) entails buffer overflow.